# How can I add search method to a list with filterable on the new list adapter?

Tags: android

As you can see, below is my class `UserAdapter` which uses latest `ListAdapter` which uses DiffUtil callback. In the original Adapter, I could easily implement Filterable and set me coming list to a filterable list, But here I don't seem to have control over selecting the list.

```
class UserAdapter(private val callback: (Int) -> Unit):
        ListAdapter<User, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(DIFF_CALLBACK) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val newsBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<UserDataBinding>(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                R.layout.user_view,
                parent,
                false)

        return UserViewHolder(newsBinding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        (holder as UserViewHolder).bindTo(getItem(position))
        holder.getDataBinding().container.setOnClickListener {
            callback.invoke(position)
        }
        holder.getDataBinding().executePendingBindings()
    }

    companion object {
        val DIFF_CALLBACK= object: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<User>() {

            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: User?, newItem: User?): Boolean {
                return oldItem?.id == newItem?.id
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: User?, newItem: User?): Boolean {
                return oldItem?.name == newItem?.name
                        && oldItem?.email == newItem?.email
                        && oldItem?.phoneNumber == newItem?.phoneNumber
                        && oldItem?.city == newItem?.city
                        && oldItem?.taluka == newItem?.taluka
                        && oldItem?.state == newItem?.state
                        && oldItem?.category == newItem?.category
                        && oldItem?.profileUrl == newItem?.profileUrl
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: here you have such generic `Filterable` adapter: https://gist.github.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85

Comment: I know the implementation in the link, I just don't want to use the old RecyclerView Adapter, it has so much boiler plate code in there. I need to use it with the new ListAdapter. I have something in mind, may be I should call submit list with the filterable list and then it might work

Comment: did you see the adapter i posted? what is boilerplate code here: https://pastebin.com/raw/LEena3pM ? yes, it is a complete code and the adapter is filterable: you can just call `adapter.getFilter().filter(...)` on it

Comment: Hi, By the way Your code looks much cleaner. But I have found the solution if any one wants to add it in the ListAdapter which uses diff utils

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the code, I have added the user list as a parameter and created a function which updates the list parameter. Also, instead of assigning filtered list I have called submitList().

```
class UserAdapter(private var mLstUser: MutableList<User>, private val callback: (Int) -> Unit):
        ListAdapter<User, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(DIFF_CALLBACK), Filterable {
    var mFilteredList: MutableList<User> = mLstUser

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val newsBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<UserDataBinding>(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                R.layout.user_view,
                parent,
                false)

        return UserViewHolder(newsBinding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        (holder as UserViewHolder).bindTo(getItem(position))
        holder.getDataBinding().container.setOnClickListener {
            callback.invoke(position)
        }

        holder.getDataBinding().executePendingBindings()
    }

    fun updateList(lstUser: MutableList<User>) {
        mLstUser = lstUser
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return object : Filter() {
            override fun performFiltering(charSequence: CharSequence): Filter.FilterResults {

                val charString = charSequence.toString()

                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    mFilteredList = mLstUser
                } else {

                    val filteredList = mLstUser
                            .filter { it.name?.toLowerCase()?.contains(charString)!! }
                            .toMutableList()

                    mFilteredList = filteredList
                }

                val filterResults = Filter.FilterResults()
                filterResults.values = mFilteredList
                return filterResults
            }

            override fun publishResults(charSequence: CharSequence, filterResults: Filter.FilterResults) {
                submitList(filterResults.values as MutableList<User>)
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        val DIFF_CALLBACK= object: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<User>() {

            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: User?, newItem: User?): Boolean {
                return oldItem?.id == newItem?.id
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: User?, newItem: User?): Boolean {
                return oldItem?.name == newItem?.name
                        && oldItem?.email == newItem?.email
                        && oldItem?.phoneNumber == newItem?.phoneNumber
                        && oldItem?.city == newItem?.city
                        && oldItem?.taluka == newItem?.taluka
                        && oldItem?.state == newItem?.state
                        && oldItem?.category == newItem?.category
                        && oldItem?.profileUrl == newItem?.profileUrl
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, why you're calling the `notifyDataSetChanged` after `submitList`? Doesn't it the submitList already notifying the adapter?

Answer (score 2):

[@nayan dhabarde](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52333209/4300670) gave us a great `kotlin` solution and here comes the same solution, but for `Java`:

I implemented the searchView in my **Fragment** like below:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getContext().SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));

        searchView.setQueryHint("Pesquisar...");
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (newText.isEmpty()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onQueryTextChange: EMPTY");
                    adapter.getFilter().filter("");
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onQueryTextChange: search text is "+newText.toString());
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
```

And below is my adapter:

```
public class StoreShoppingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StoreShoppingAdapter.StoreShoppingViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private static final String TAG = "debinf StoreShopAda";

    private LocalDatabaseViewModel localDatabaseViewModel;

    private List<StoreEntity> fullList;

    public StoreShoppingAdapter(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
        this.localDatabaseViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(fragmentActivity).get(LocalDatabaseViewModel.class);

    }

    private static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<StoreEntity> DIFF_CALLBACK = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<StoreEntity>() {
        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull StoreEntity oldItem, @NonNull StoreEntity newItem) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull StoreEntity oldItem, @NonNull StoreEntity newItem) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    private AsyncListDiffer<StoreEntity> differ = new AsyncListDiffer<StoreEntity>(this, DIFF_CALLBACK);

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public StoreShoppingViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_shopping_store, parent, false);
        return new StoreShoppingViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StoreShoppingViewHolder holder, int position) {
        StoreEntity store = differ.getCurrentList().get(position);

        holder.storeName.setText(store.getName());
        holder.storeDate.setText("TimeStamp Here");

        if (store.getImage() != null && !store.getImage().isEmpty()) {
            Picasso.get().load(store.getImage()).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(holder.storeImage, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                    Picasso.get().load(store.getImage()).into(holder.storeImage);
                }
            });
        } else {
            holder.storeImage.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_phone_call_on_hold);
        }

        holder.storeDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                localDatabaseViewModel.deleteStore(store);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return differ.getCurrentList().size();
    }

    public void submitList(List<StoreEntity> stores) {
        differ.submitList(stores);
        fullList = new ArrayList<>(stores);
    }

    public List<StoreEntity> getCurrentItemList() {
        return differ.getCurrentList();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return shopFilter;
    }

    private Filter shopFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<StoreEntity> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(fullList);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for (StoreEntity store : fullList) {
                    if (store.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(store);
                    }
                }
            }

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            //differ.getCurrentList().clear();
            //differ.getCurrentList().addAll((List) results.values);
            differ.submitList((List) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    public class StoreShoppingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public ImageView storeImage;
        public TextView storeName, storeDate;
        public ImageButton storeDelete;

        public StoreShoppingViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            storeImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_shoppingstore_image);
            storeName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_shoppingstore_name);
            storeDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_shoppingstore_date);
            storeDelete = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_shoppingstore_delete);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StoreEntity store = differ.getCurrentList().get(getAdapterPosition());
            Log.i(TAG, "onClick: store clicked is "+store.getName());
            ShopFragmentDirections.ActionShopFragmentToShopcartFragment direction = ShopFragmentDirections.actionShopFragmentToShopcartFragment(store);
            Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(direction);
        }
    }
}
```